# Responsive HTML - How to show a `Go` button instead of `Next` on mobile keyboard

Tags: android, html, responsive-design

Ive a simple problem, Ive a form that submits on `enter` on any field. However, on a mobile `input type=text` for example doesnt show a `Go` or submit key on the keyboard.

Instead it shows or does a `next` and takes the user to next input field. Only the last field shows the Go key.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to get this working?

Here is the html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="field_1" name="field_1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="field_2" name="field_2" value="" />
<input type="text" id="field_3" name="field_3" value="" />
</form>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have to post code

Comment: check now, ive added code as well as image